# jni error in android between android ndk12b and ndk13b

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to get java float filed from a java object with jni interface.

JAVA CODE:

```
public class JavaObject immplements Serializable {
    public float floatfiled1 = 0f;
    public float floatfield2 = 0f;
}
```

JNI CODE IN C++:

```
jclass jclazz = jenv->FindClass("JavaObject");
jfieldID field_id = jenv->GetFieldID(jclazz, "floatfiled1", "F");
float test_v = jenv->GetFloatField(javaobject, field_id);
LOGD("[JNI] test_v=%f", test_v);
```

test_v always get 0.0 in many android mobile phones. and even in several mobile phone like XIAOMI3, get a very large number.

The problem is missing when using ndk12b.
**So, what't the problem with ndk13b when get float field from java object?**

Comment: You need to pass fully-qualified class name into `FindClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem.
In my jni interface Android.mk.
remove the no use falgs, and everyting is ok in ndk12b and ndk13b.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKbXp.png)